# Do differential forms and ordinary differential equations have identical solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the 1-form
$$
M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0
$$
and the ODE
$$
M(x,y) + N(x,y)y'=0.
$$
These functions seem to be identical, and if one were to abuse notation, the first equation, multiplied by $\frac{1}{dx}$ (whatever *that* means) is equivalent to the second. I believe that they have identical solutions, but my professor said that their solutions are not identical; namely that the solutions to the first are level curves of some function, can be implicit, and are expressed in the form $f(x,y) = c$, where c is constant, while the second has solutions that are functions, explicit, and are expressed in the form $y(x) = g(x,c)$, where c is constant.

Comment: What do you mean by solution to the first equation?

Comment: Aren't the only functions $M, N$ satisfying the first equation $M(x, y) = N(x, y) = 0$?

Comment: @Joppy technically yes, however, a "solution" in this case is actually a function that either implicitly or explicitly gives a value for $y$ for every valid $x$.

Comment: I believe your professor is mistaken. In the latter case, if you take the ODE $x+yy'=0$, you will likewise get an implicit solution $x^2+y^2=c$, even though the notation suggests that you have in mind an explicit function $y=f(x)$.

Comment: if your professor is correct, then all the professors I took courses with are wrong. Because the first thing they always told the class to do to check if an ODE is exact or not, is to rewrite the ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ in the form $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$ as a first step. The ODE's you show are exactly the same. Hence they have the same solution. One can always convert an implicit solution to an explicit if needed.

Comment: Solutions to the 1-form equation are curves $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$. Solutions of the ODE are functions $y(x)$. Any such function satisfying the ODE defines a curve satisfying the 1-form equation. But the opposite is not true. The easiest example is when $M = 1, N = 0$. The 1-form equation has solutions $\gamma(t) = (c, t)$ for various $c$. But the ODE is just "$1 = 0$", so it has no solution.

Comment: @PaulSinclair clear and concise. Additionally, the example is really helpful. Thanks! I would select this comment as an answer if it were one.